# Renaming a MySQL table in a Zend/Doctrine PHP app fails?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine

I have a PHP backend application which is used both by an administration interface and a game. I know my way around PHP but I'm not familiar with Zend and Doctrine.

There's just two tables in MySQL (for schools and for students) and I want to change their name prefixes, because they refer to an earlier release of the game.

In short: I renamed the tables, I modified all PHP references to use the new names. There is not a trace of the old name anymore in all the Zend and Doctrine folders. But now the web application fails because it is still looking for the old names.

Here's the error: 
**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db1.neverland_schools' doesn't exist**

So what happened is I changed the table name from neverland_schools to adventure_schools. It still looks for the old table name.

What I suspect is this being *cache*. But I don't have command line access to the server, nor experience with talking to Doctrine via command line.

If cache is the problem, would there be a way to reset the cache from PHP?
And if something else is the problem, I'd love to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your school entity, i think i know where the problem is , but i need to make sure

Answer (score 0):

If you have base class defined You must change name of schools and students `base` class. Path for base classess is in your config, or bootstrap file.

If not have you tried setting the table name explicitly, as in the first line 
of the method below?

```
class Adventure_Schools extends Doctrine_Record { 
    public function setTableDefinition () { 
        $this->setTableName('adventure_schools');
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the thing is: I've done a raw text search through the entire source code looking for the old name, and it is not anywhere to be found anymore. So that includes bootstraps, application.ini and routes.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the cache data :

1. you can emoty the tempory folder of the server
2. [delete Doctrine cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#deleting)

   $deleted = $cacheDriver->deleteAll();

Maybe you should empty the proxy folder also.

You can verify that you changed the table name in the metadta depending on the driver.
if you are using the yaml or xml maybe the plin text serch doesn't take in ccount the file formt.

**anotation**

```
// entities/Product.php
/**
 * @Entity **@Table(name="products")**
 **/
```

**xml**

```
<entity name="Product" table="products">
```

**yaml**

```
# config/yaml/Product.dcm.yml
Product:
  type: entity
  table: products
```